# Flow - HTTP Callout with proprietary auth method

Tags: visual-workflow

I am trying to connect to the [Personio API](https://developer.personio.de/reference/introduction) from within Salesforce using a flow.
I have created an External Service and the corresponding Action for the Auth and another External Service and Action for the Personnel Data.
However, even though I am able to receive the token from the first Action, I can't seem to pass the token to the second Action as I don't see somewhere the option to provide a header.
Is this even possible using Named/External credentials or am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at https://developer.personio.de/reference/post_auth, this is a proprietary auth method, thus you're out of luck when it comes to out of the box, no-code solution. Even if you grab the token, you can't use it in a Callout action in a Flow - it doesn't allow you to dynamically add headers. You'll need to use plain Apex (without a Flow) or Invocable Action (still Apex) inside a Flow.

Comment: Thank you @identigral. I suspected this is the case but I hoped there is a way since Personio provides OpenAPI specification and the creation of external services was a breeze.